# Svetekit: How can I change path of form action?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I want to change the path of actions dynamically with use:enhance.

However, my code is not working as I expected. It always redirect to "?/error". Not "?/a"

```
<script>
  import { enhance } from "$app/forms";
  /** @type {import("./$types").SubmitFunction} */
  const handleSubmit = ({formData, action}) => {
    switch(formData.get("type")) {
      case "a":
        action = new URL("?/a", action);
        console.log(action) // action changed.
        break;
        // And So On...
    }
  }
</script>
<form action="?/error" use:enhance={handleSubmit}>
  <button name="type" value="a">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anything, you would have to modify the source event object; modifying a destructured primitive value does not affect it. But SvelteKit does not care about that either.

You should just change it in the template, buttons can do that natively. E.g.

```html
<form action="?/error" method="post" use:enhance>
    <button formaction="?/a">A</button>
    <button formaction="?/b">B</button>
</form>
```

(You also need to POST, in case that was missing)